# Правильно ли объявлять много переменных в одном классе?

Tags: java, ооп

Допустим работа осуществляется в доп.потоке, при сворачивании приложения и разворачивании приложения, поток убивается и создается новый. (т.к. поток не сразу останавливается, как я понял, рекомендуется создавать новый поток). Если переменные объявлены в потоке, при создании нового экземпляра потока, они потеряются. Если вывести объявление переменных в Main класс он нагромождается. Мне интересно влияет ли на производительность объявление большого числа переменных в одном классе. Это раз. Для визуальной красоты, для хранения переменных может быть создан отдельный класс, правильно ли так поступать? Хочется знать, учитывая все тонкости, какой подход используют хорошие программисты. Может тот вариант, который я описал нормальный и ничего другого не надо придумывать.

Comment: Какая-то путаница. И ООП и потоки и переменные... А так все зависит от контекста задачи. Если это академическая задача для курсовой - то будет один подход. Если это продакшен код - то другой.

Comment: Я просто пишу первое свое приложение на Java , до этого год усиленно занимался qbasic , так что образование у меня не программистское, вот и возникают такого рода вопросы. Не ставьте вопрос в рамки какой то конкретной задачи. А интересует меня всегда Как сделать производительность еще выше (хотя она уже не требуется, люблю идеальные алгоритмы) и вопрос Как делают хорошие программисты,которые учли все аспекты вопроса (они посмотрели нужна ли эта производительность, насколько важна визуальная красота и не забыли учесть правила хорошего тона) .

Comment: Абстрагирование от конкретной задачи - это сродни поиску смысла жизни. Занятие увлекательное, но бесполезное.

Comment: Ладно, я сам не могу уже конкретизировать вопрос и больше кажется ,что никаких проблем множественное объявление переменных не принесет.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312642/how-many-classes-per-package-methods-per-class-lines-per-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Мой ответ будет очень неоднозначный и субъективный.*

Если в класс много переменных то это уже не правильный класс. А неправильный он скорее всего из-за неправильно архитектуры. Хранить всё в Main плохо.

Большое количество переменных в классе влияет на производительность если часто работать с объектами этого класса. То есть создавать, удалять, клонировать и чем больше переменных тем сложнее это делать.

То что ты называешь

> хранения переменных может быть создан отдельный класс

это называется паттерн(тебе уже дали ссылку на них) **Value Object**.

Рефакторь архитектуру, в правильной у тебя не должно возникать подобных проблем.

@Turalllb MVC это не паттерн, а концепция и отношение к этому вопросу она не имеет. Вы не правильно используете потоки. Поток в программе не должен выполнять какие то другие функции программы, а должен асинхронно выполнять функции основной программы.

Comment: вот это мне и нужно было знать, влияет ли это на производительность. Я понял, что этот паттерн для случае с большим числом переменных, но мне, как я посчитал, больше подходит паттерн MVC . У меня переменных на самом деле не очень то и много , вопрос я задал на будущее, если вдруг понадобится с большим числом переменых работать. Пока я не посмотрел Value Object, не могли ли бы вы мне ответить, где хранить переменные  ,которые надо объявлять вне доп.потоков.

Comment: Если создать отдельный класс, где только объявляются переменные и запускать этот класс из Main класса , в главном потоке, ситуация с производительностью конечно не изменится, но зато визуально всё будет более читабельно. Но чтобы получать эти переменные придется их объявлять как статик. Какие есть другие способы получить эти переменные из доп.потоков?

Comment: @Turalllb получить доступ из другого потока на не статик нельзя(разве что создать ещё один класс в котором хранить такие переменные и получать указатель на этот класс через статик).

Answer (score 2):

Steve McConnell в своей книге Code Complete 1993-го года рекомендовал использовать около 7 методов на класс. При этом количество строк в каждом методе должно быть таким, чтобы они помещались на экране без использования прокрутки.
Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312650/872294

В последствии эти и другие рекомендации были включены в "линтеры" (linters) - программы, проверяющие качество кода. Линтеры часто используются в составе интегрированных средств разработки (IDE), которые просто не дают программисту писать слишком плохой код.

Поэтому сейчас более актуален совет от Linus Torvalds: чтобы отличить плохого программиста от хорошего, спросите у него, что он считает более важным: стиль кода или структуры данных
Источник: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/torvalds-quote-about-good-programmer